# How to get value of a html text field in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a Python code, and when I enter 127.0.0.1\dateform as an example it shows a simple HTML page which is created by Python, and it has just a textbox, and a submit button. Now I wanted get the value of the textbox. I almost tried everything that I could but I couldn't find anything. By the way I'm very new in Python.

Please let me know how it is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Old good cgi :)

I hope you've already set your cgi enviroment. [Useful resource](https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/129-servers/757148-configuring-apache2-to-run-python-scripts). [Another useful resource](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html#setting-up-cgi-on-your-own-server)

Let's say you have a form

**form.html**

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/form.py" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Text input: <input maxlength="60" size="60" value="0" name="textinput"> 

<input value="Submit" type="submit">

</form>
```

**form.py** (inside cgi-bin folder)

```
import cgi   

form = cgi.FieldStorage()   
# html form inputs are simple key value pairs - 
#in php they are associative arrays
#in ruby they are hashes
# and in python dictionaries
# keys are form elements' name (in our example 'textinput')
# values are user inputs
input_text = form.getfirst("textinput", "0") # 0 is optional - if no 
#values entered automatically set it to "0". same as
#>>> x = {2:"a"}
#>>> x.get(2, "nonexistent")
#'a'
#>>> x.get(3, "nonexistent")
#'nonexistent'
#have a look up this -http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<body>"
#print "<p>%s</p>" % form  #uncomment this line if you want 
#to see what does form hashes look like 
print "<p>%s</p>" % input_text
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

First is to use forms:

```
<forms action="/path/to/function" method="post">
    <textarea name="text_box">This is the value</textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the value of the textarea will be available in the request object(if you are using Django):

```
text_box_value = request.GET['text_box']
```

Second option is to use JavaScript, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: As far as I know I can't use the path, because I don't know where file will be used, and no I don't use Django.

Comment: what web framework are you using? In any case, that framework should have a way of working with some form of `request` object and urls.

Comment: I'm just using Python. Inside the code I'm running a server, using socket, and bind and listen.
I tried to get the values with cgi, but FieldStorage always is empty.